# Google Maps website KML track display issue

Tags: google-maps, kml, kmz

I'm converting recorded GPS tracks to KML/KMZ files and they show up correctly in Google Earth. However, opening the same KML file in the Google Maps *website* I get weird straight lines that are a few thousand km long.

KML download: 
http://www.indunet.it/stackexchange/test.kml

Direct link to Google Maps website:
https://maps.google.com/maps?q=http:%2F%2Fwww.indunet.it%2Fstackexchange%2Ftest.kml&hl=de&sll=37.230328,-95.712891&sspn=52.421131,114.169922&t=h&z=4

This is what the KML file looks like on my computer:

[image]

I get identical results with FF, Chrome and IE, so I guess it's somethign related to the generated KML file, but I have no clue what's wrong..

Oddly, zooming in to the correct area (upper-left end of the line, i.e. northern Italy) shows some outline that's similar to the original track:

[image]

Correct display in Google Earth (same KML file):

[image]

Any ideas?

PS: I get similar results with all tracks I export. However, markers always show up correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your kml has the coordinates specified:
11.30968602,46.35330003,

If I add a third coordinate it works:
[11.30968602,46.35330003,0](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/indunet_test_kmlA.xml) [[on google maps](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=http%3a%2F%2Fwww.geocodezip.com%2Findunet_test_kmlA.xml&hl=en&ll=46.313976,11.25927&spn=0.142281,0.220757&sll=37.588909,-87.337822&sspn=0.005135,0.006899&t=m&z=120)]

or if I remove the comma at the end it works:
[11.30968602,46.35330003](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/indunet_test_kmlB.xml) [[on google maps](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=http%3a%2F%2Fwww.geocodezip.com%2Findunet_test_kmlB.xml&hl=en&ll=46.313976,11.25927&spn=0.142281,0.220757&sll=37.588909,-87.337822&sspn=0.005135,0.006899&t=m&z=12)]